# "far longer" vs. "for far longer"

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

1. > We thus can keep their trust **far longer**.
2. > We thus can keep their trust **for far longer**.

Are 1 and 2 both correct and meaning the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Susan -
Yes, they are both technically correct; using the additional word "for" is more common in formal writing and speaking.